# How to use Fun<XELEMENT,bool> in where when loadin XML file

Tags: xml, linq, predicate, func

I did  the  example  below

```
 IEnumerable<string> names = from student in XDocument.Load(@"E:\Data.xml").Element("Students").Elements("Student").Where(i=>(int)i.Element("TotalMarks") > 800)
                                    orderby (int)student.Element("TotalMarks") descending
                                    select student.Element("Name").Value;

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

this  example  simply  load xml doc from  local HD .  i filtered the result  by using where  extension method that belong  to  Elements, i implented  the  filter by  lambda  expression  . now please can  anyone help me  how to achive the same results but  using  Func(<'XELEMENT,bool'> predicate) option . 
by the way this code work on console application you can hover above where and see the Func in clear way.
here are the xml file  its name  Data.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Creating an XML Tree using LINQ to XML-->
<Students>
  <Student Id="101">
    <Name>Mark</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>800</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="102">
    <Name>Rosy</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>900</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="103">
    <Name>Pam</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>850</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="104">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>950</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a separate function you wish to use instead of the inline lambda, here it is:

```
private bool MyFilter(XElement elt)
{
    return (int)elt.Element("TotalMarks") > 800;
}

// then in your query ... Where(i=>MyFilter(i)) ...
```

Comment: MyFilter is more versatile if the limit value is a parameter.